# Need some suggestions how to achieve pl/sql insert looping over two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have three tables employee, department, hrrecords

employee table:

| emp id | empname |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | aaa |
| 102 | bbb |
| 103 | ccc |

Department Table:

| dep id | dep name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X |
| 2 | Y |
| 3 | Z |

I need to insert data from the above two tables into  table 'hrrecords' like this

| emp id | dep id |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 101 | 3 |
| 102 | 1 |
| 102 | 2 |
| 102 | 3 |
| 103 | 1 |
| 103 | 2 |
| 103 | 3 |

I wanted to do this using loops, any suggestions please ?

Comment: You need to use loops because you are studying them, right?  Your task can be solved without any loop

Comment: Do you really want each employee to belong to every department??

Comment: The result looks like cross product of two tables that doesn't make much sense. Also SQL is not an procedural language, you do not need any loops to join two tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to do this using loops, any suggestions please ?

You can create a procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE loop_insert IS
  cursor c1 
  is
  select emp_id 
  from employee;
  
  cursor c2
  is
  select dep_id 
  from Department;
  
BEGIN
    for v1 in c1 loop
        for v2 in c2 loop
            insert into mytable values(v1.emp_id, v2.dep_id);
        end loop;
    end loop;
END loop_insert;
/
```

and then you can execute it like this:

```
begin
    loop_insert;
end;
/
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1206124e84f578d851911b864ceb48ac)

Comment: I always appreciate it if you can comment your downvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its not the best solution, but it should work in your case:

```
insert into hrrecords
select emp_id, dep_id
from employee, department
```